# Open-source linux scanner

Tags: linux, scanner

I want to buy a scanner for my future Linux machine. But I am worried about spyware since scanners bundle third-party proprietary software with the scanner and printer manufacturers already use [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Identification_Code).

Does any company sell open-source scanners with the same business model as the [MakerBot Replicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makerbot#Replicator), whose plans were open-source and the company had profits from customers who didn't want to make the 3D printer from scratch?

Comment: on the OCR side of things, which is a significant component of scanner software bundles, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software) quite effectively.

Comment: Yes, I will use an open source OCR such as Tesseract, OCRopus, or ScanTailor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Free Software Foundation has made a list of GNU/Linux compatible hardwares, freely editable by anyone with an account, which can be found here:

https://www.fsf.org/resources/hw

Then after going to that website go to H-node's search (H-node is the directory of FOSS hardware):

https://h-node.org/

And go to scanners category:

https://h-node.org/scanners/catalogue/en

As of August 2018, the [list of scanners with full compatibility with free software](https://h-node.org/scanners/catalogue/en/1/1/undef/A-Full/undef/undef/compatibility/undef) has 6 models with commercialization dates between 2002 and 2011.

Edit 2022:

Definitely also checkout the RYF (Respects Your Freedom) certification by the FSF https://ryf.fsf.org/products .
While there aren't any scanners yet, it's a really good cert for libre hardware and new entries will be added in the future.

Comment: fwiw it's worth, though this is from a long time ago, I've had **extremely** poor results from a member of the Canoscan family under both Linux and macos.